# Compute income via date

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains name(varchar),date(datetime), and income(money) for the specific date

EXAMPLE:

```
robert 10/10/13 1200.0000
jacob 10/10/19  2300.0000
```

How do I compute my total income from a specific date(Like from 10/10/13 to 10/10/28)

Comment: What do the dates represent - a specific income event on that date, or some change to income level (i.e. salary) that becomes effective on that date and must be further calculated to determine portion of that salary for date range?  Note you should use a date, datetime, or timestamp field for storage of your dates, not some other ambiguous date formatted string field.

Comment: It's the daily of someone. I want to determine the total amount of all persons income in a specific date difference like 15 days(January 1 - 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all:

```
SELECT name_column, sum(IFNULL(amount_column, 0))
FROM income_table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '[INSERT FROM DATE]' AND '[INSERT UNTIL DATE]'
GROUP BY name_columns
```

For one:

```
SELECT sum(IFNULL(amount_column, 0))
FROM income_table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '[INSERT FROM DATE]' AND '[INSERT UNTIL DATE]'
AND name_column = '[INSERT NAME]'
```

Comment: Note to OP. This will not work with your current data formats as shown, you should change `date` field to be of type date, datetime, or timestamp (whichever is appropriate). The field itself should probably not be named `date` as this is also a function name.

Comment: And income table should probably not be named income_table. But there was no names in the question. No data types either.

Comment: There is no problem with `income_table` in your example.  I just wanted to make sure OP thought before using a filed name like `date` specifically because the table schema wasn't noted in the question.

Comment: The result in mine is null

Comment: Have you replaced the column and table names? And sorry, I put the from and until-dates in the wrong order. I've changed it now.

Comment: Yes i have replaced it

Comment: How does it look then?

Comment: There is a result. It says NULL

Comment: SELECT SUM(income)
    FROM report
   WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-02'

Comment: @user3235016 is `date` a `varchar` field with data as `2014/03/01`? if it is then `BETWEEN` will give no results. See my answer I have also included a link showing how it would work and how it would not work.

Comment: What does this returns? select data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'report' 
and column_name = 'date'

Comment: Maybe you have NULL values in the income column? I changed the query a bit.

Comment: @user3235016 are you joining your report table with a users table perhaps?

Comment: Try using backticks around `date` field name